Minimal ideals of $k[x,y]/(x^2y, x(x + y))$
I need some help computing the minimal ideals of    $$
\frac{k[x, y]}{(x^2y,x(x + y))}
    $$
This is what I know: every ideal of this ring is of the form $J/(x^2y, x(x + y))$ where $J$ is an ideal in $k[x,y]$ that contains $(x^2y, x(x + y))$.
Just out of curiosity, what would be the minimal prime ideals of it?

Hint: suppose $x^2y\in P$, What can you say about $P$? What about $x(x+y)$?

If $P$ were prime, then $x^2 \in P$ or $y\in P$, so $x\in P$ or $y\in P$. In the other case, we arrive at   $x\in P$ or $x+y\in P$. But here I don't have that $P$ is prime. Could you elaborate please?

OK, so you know $x\in P$ or $y\in P$.  In the second case, you also have $x(x+y) \in P$, and along with $y\in P$ you get $x^2\in P$...

In fact, it appears using a Groebner basis calculation that $x^3 \in P$ already (though at the moment I don't have the exact combination that would directly show $x^3 \in P$).

I was thinking about using a kind of chinese remainder theorem to simplify this quotient ring or the isomorphism theorems, but really don't know how to proceed. Notice that we don't know $P$ is prime.

$x^3=0$ is easy to deduce. $0 = x x (x+y) = x^3 + x^2 y = x^3$.
